# C++ Self defined function declaration error: unknown type name

Tags: c++

I am using this to declare a user defined function to calculate the discriminant for quadratic equations:

```
double discriminant(double a, b, c){
  return b * b - 4 * a * c;
}
```

But for some reason I get the following errors:

```
 Error: unknown type name 'b'
double calcDiscriminant(double a, b, c){
                                  ^
 error: unknown type name 'c'
double calcDiscriminant(double a, b, c){
                                     ^
error: use of undeclared identifier 'b'
  return b * b - 4 * a * c;
         ^
error: use of undeclared identifier 'b'
  return b * b - 4 * a * c;
             ^
error: use of undeclared identifier 'c'
```

I'm defining the function right after

```
using namespace std;
```

So I really don't understand what I'm doing wrong here? I actually found this elsewhere and it's supposed to be a valid function declaration but I can't get it to work.

Comment: In an arg list: double a, double b, double c.

Comment: Voting to close as a typo.  `double discriminant(double a, b, c)`1 should be `double discriminant(double a, double b, double c)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When we declare a function with parameters then we have to write data-type of every parameter respectively. So, in function declaration where you have written this:

```cpp
double discriminant(double a, b, c) {
    return b * b - 4 * a * c;
}
```

Declare it like this:

```cpp
double discriminant(double a, double b, double c) {
    return b * b - 4 * a * c;
}
```